# Drag-and-drop accordion panels? (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, drag-and-drop, accordion

I have a set of accordion panes(dynamically created) contained in an Accordion control. Basically, what I am wanting is for the user to be capable of dragging these accordion panels so that instead of

```
A pane
B pane
C pane
```

They can drag and drop it to be something like

```
B pane
A pane
C pane
```

Or whatever. Also, more importantly, I would need to be able to detect that they have changed the order. Would there be a way to have it when they "drop" the pane that it can update a hidden field or something? I don't need a postback on every single drag and drop, but rather I want for when they hit a save button for the server application to detect the order in which the panes are so that it can save this order.

I would prefer to stay away from javascript libraries, but if it would be the easiest way, then I'll consider it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [petersendidit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791103/drag-and-drop-accordion-panels-asp-net/1840044#1840044) but without "disappearing accordion" bug...

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div id="section_1">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>
        Body 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="section_2">
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>
        Body 2
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="section_3">
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <p>
        Body 3
        </p>
    </div>
<div id="section_4">
        <h3>Section 4</h3>
        <p>
        Body 4
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header:'h3'
}).sortable({
    items:'>div'
});
```

Demo at: https://jsbin.com/bitiyucasa

Comment: Recommend using >div.[ACCORDION PANE CLASS]

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong but that demo does NOT work for me at all

Comment: @daveL No, you're right - it looks like it stopped working sometime in the last 5 years...

Comment: @DaveLawrence - I (finally) took a look at that today - it appears that the jquery libraries it was referencing were out of date. I've updated them again, and it's working now.

Comment: @Stobor fair play for taking a look again 6 years later :) I've moved on from jquery days thankfully!

Comment: @Dave So have I, that's part of why it took so long. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/):

```
$("#accordion").accordion()
.sortable({
    items:'>.ui-accordion-header',
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $content = ui.item.next();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.after($content);
    }
});
```

This sets $content to the content div for that header on change. And then on stop moves that content to be after the new position of the header.

HTML would be something like:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="section_1"><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Body 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3 id="section_2"><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Body 2
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3 id="section_3"><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Body 3
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3 id="section_4"><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Body 4
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When your user hits the "save" button you can just call:

```
$('#accordion').sortable( 'serialize');
```

Which will give you something like:

```
section[]=2&section[]=1&section[]=3&section[]=4
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not allow me to drag and drop the accordion panes in order to resort them. I used your near exact code and it did not allow drag and drop. I've never used jquery before, so there might be some trivial error with your code I'm not seeing

Comment: Ok. I wasn't including the jqueryui file.(just jquery). Anyway, that looks pretty good. Is jquery designed to do this? Because I spotted a pretty bad bug where you can drop panes in other panes so that they disappear.(it's easy to do without intending to also)

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't support this but with some work you probably could get it working pretty well. If anything you could extend the jQuery UI Accordion and Sortable and modify it to make it work how you want to.

Comment: Well your answer was great but I have to go with @stobor cause it's ready made.. If only I could give you both the answer! lol

Answer (score 1):

- **This [widget](http://aariadne.com/accordion/accordion.html) is probably the sort of thing you are after.**

You can add links to the javascript in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="accordion.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Ext.ux.InfoPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Ext.ux.Accordion.js"></script>
```

The markup is then just a series of divs. With a little bit of effort you should be able to tie this into the accordion control or create a user control to do your bidding

```
 <div id="acc-ct" style="width:200px;height:300px">
  <div id="panel-1">
    <div>My first panel</div>
    <div>
      <div class="text-content">My first panel content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel-2">
    <div>My second panel</div>
    <div>
      <div class="text-content">My second panel content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A preview of it is available [here](http://aariadne.com/accordion-preview/)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll leave this question open to hope for something a little cheaper than $1,299.(we're developing proprietary software) That does seem to be exactly what we want though.

Comment: I hadn't realised there was a commercial license cost with it sorry :( - certainly comprehensive though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use predefined dojo control (open source javascript framework)([link text](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/))  and use this control from here ([link text](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-2-dijit/layout/accordion-container)) .You can also integrate dojo with asp.net like on my blog ([link text](http://madicemickael.wordpress.com/)).

Waiting for response of your success